# Line in Python to PHP

Tags: php, python

My question is quite simple, I have a line written in Python and I want to translate to PHP. I would like to know what this code means, can anyone help me?

```
key = file['k'][file['k'].index(':') + 1:]
```

PHP writing, `$file` looks like:

```
stdClass Object ( [h] => EtJ2BShT [p] => RgwTgawT [u] => Wh2yQMRtPnM [t] => 0 [a] => 7t-LChJ3ipLxISzHTJ3P8ctqt5YYZoXXJ_3uQwc65sU [k] => Wh2yQMRtPnM:dmcr_plTOPAS75PLnr3qlXZnK_6ZUzjwEu-Ty5696pU [s] => 85 [ts] => 1398630915 )
```

So, if I understood your comments, `$key = dmcr_plTOPAS75PLnr3qlXZnK_6ZUzjwEu-Ty5696pU` is the correct answer. Ok?

Comment: Do you know what kind of object `file['k']` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `file['k']` is a string, here's the equivalent in PHP:

```
$key = substr(file['k'], strpos(file['k'], ':') + 1);
```

Comment: Your line would not have the same behavior - `list`s do not have a `split` method, and in a string it would grab everything after the *last* colon and be transformed into a `list`. OP's code grabs everything after the *first* colon and retains it as a list or string.

Answer (score 1):

This line will take everything from `file['k']` after the first colon. For example:

```
>>> teststr = 'hello:world'
>>> teststr[teststr.index(':') + 1:]
'world'
```

Breaking it up into its parts:

```
>>> teststr.index(':')
5
>>> teststr[5]
':'
>>> teststr[5:]
':world'
>>> teststr[6:]
'world'
```

Here I'm using a string, but this will behave in the same way if `file['k']` is a list:

```
>>> testlist = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ':', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> testlist[testlist.index(':')+1:]
['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```